# int bitparity's explaination

Tags: c, bit, parity

I have to create a function bitParity(int x) that takes an integer and returns 1 if there is an odd number of 0's in the bit form of x, and 0 otherwise.

Ex: bitParity(5) = 0, bitParity(7) = 1
Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

My buddy shared his code with me, but when I did the calculation from scratch, it seems to get the opposite of what he gets, can someone please explain this code a little bit so I get the idea of how it functioning?

```
int bitParity(int x) {
x = ( x >> 16 ) ^ x;
x = ( x >> 8 ) ^ x;
x = ( x >> 4 ) ^ x;
x = ( x >> 2 ) ^ x;
x = ( x >> 1 ) ^ x;

    return (x & 1);
}
```

Comment: The behavior of >> on signed values is unspecified.  So you'd better make the argument *unsigned* if you want a predictable result.

Answer (score 0):

This function is basically `xor`ing all the bits of the input number and putting it at the LSB, hence gives `1` if there are odd number of `1`s.

**How it Works:**

- Take input of `8-bit`, say `11001001`.
- For `8-bit` input you need to start from 3rd statement of code: `x = ( x >> 4 ) ^ x;`
- Doing so (Step 1), you get:

  x<sub>7</sub>  x<sub>6</sub>  x<sub>5</sub>  x<sub>4</sub>  x<sub>7</sub>^x<sub>3</sub>  x<sub>6</sub>^x<sub>2</sub>  x<sub>5</sub>^x<sub>1</sub>  x<sub>4</sub>^x<sub>0</sub>

where x<sub>i</sub> denotes `ith` bit of `x`.

- Now Step 2: `x = ( x >> 2 ) ^ x;` gives:

  x<sub>6</sub>^x<sub>2</sub>^x<sub>4</sub>^x<sub>0</sub>           at the LSB of `x`, and
  x<sub>7</sub>^x<sub>3</sub>^x<sub>5</sub>^x<sub>1</sub>           at bit position `1` of `x`.  Rest positions are not relevant.
- Step 3: `x = ( x >> 1 ) ^ x;` which finally gives:

  x<sub>6</sub>^x<sub>2</sub>^x<sub>4</sub>^x<sub>0</sub>^x<sub>7</sub>^x<sub>3</sub>^x<sub>5</sub>^x<sub>1</sub>           at the LSB of `x`.
- Last Step: `return (x & 1);` which returns value of this expression, which is `xor` of all the bits in `x` which is `1` if and only if number of `1`s in `x` is odd.
- You can extend this to `16-bit`, `32-bit` or `64-bit` numbers.
- Also, notice that **finding odd number of `0`s is equivalent to finding odd numbers of `1`s**, since total number of `1`s and `0`s add up to even number of bits.
- Therefore, above code should work correctly for you